# A specific improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have been given the following improper integral to evaluate

> $$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2-1}{\log{x}} dx $$

I tried substituting $ u = \log{x} $ which gives the following improper integral
$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{e^{3u}-e^{u}}{u} du $ 
This integral can be evaluated by software like Wolfram but I am interested in the method. How does one solve the integral analytically? I have no real idea on this. Thanks to all helpers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{e^{3u}-e^{u}}{u} du=\int_{-\infty}^{0} \int_1^3 e^{xu}\ dx\ du=\int_1^3 \int_{-\infty}^{0}  e^{xu}\ du\ dx=\int_1^3 \dfrac1x\ dx=\ln3$$

Comment: This is a classic Frullani integral - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral